# Is a rook ending where the winning side has a passed g and d pawns drawn?

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame

The passed pawns are g and d pawns. Can the losing side draw such a rook endgame? Can you give some examples to how or why it can't be drawn?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a specific diagram or two.

Comment: You should change the tilte as it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

By definition if there's a "winning side" and a "losing side" then
the question is already answered :-)

But seriously, if you just want K+R+P(d)+P(g) vs. K+R, that's within
database range, so you can explore for yourself
[here](http://k4it.de/index.php?topic=egtb&lang=en).
In general such positions are easy wins (note that the defending
King can "always" be cut off from one pawn or the other by a
Rook move to e or f), though naturally there are some initial positions 
where one pawn is lost tactically to leave a draw, and there can even
be "accidents" such as this:

```
6r1/8/7k/8/3P1KP1/8/8/4R3 w - - 0 0

1. Kf5?? Rf8+ 0-1
```